# How to avoid ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exceptions when querying multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have this code:

```
Article.find([1,2,3])
```

But only record **1** and **2** exist in the database. I get this exception:

```
"ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find all Offers with IDs (1,2,3) (found 2 results, but was looking for 3))"
```

Is there a way to only get the existing records and not the exception?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Article.find_all_by_id([1,2,3])` is the way to go!

Comment: or `Article.find_by_id(1)` if you're just looking for one

Comment: this is deprecated now, see the other answers

Answer (score 13):

Rails 3+, ruby 1.9+  way:

```
Article.where(id: [1,2,3])
```

Comment: Thank you for adding this, the other answers are a bit outdated :)

Comment: As noted - this should be the correct answer for more recent version of rails.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that using find with ids raises exceptions when the records are missing. You could try something like

```
Article.all :conditions => ["id in (?)", [1,2,3]]
```

or more succinctly

```
Article.find_all_by_id [1,2,3]
```

using `find :all` does not raise errors on missing records, so even if the records are missing you are cool.